# How to have a class change an attribute for another class in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, inheritance

I want to have my `Teacher` class take attendance for each `Student` and change the student's label to either `absent` or `present`. I want it to do this for each particular day in a school year before saving all labels and students' names into a `.txt` file.
I'm not sure how to have it label each student for each day, though.

I've tried many codes before putting this raw one here so no one gets confused.

```py
class Person():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, national_id, living_area, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        self.national_id = national_id
        self.living_area = living_area
        self.email = email

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, national_id, living_area, email, work_experience, salary):
        super.__init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, national_id, living_area, email)
        self.work_experience = work_experience
        self.salary = salary
    
    def taking_attendance(self, label):
        pass

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, national_id, living_area, email, grade):
        super.__init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, national_id, living_area, email)
        self.grade = grade

    def attendance(self, label):
        pass
```

Comment: What is `taking_attendance` in `Teacher` supposed to do, and why is it being passed a `label`?

Comment: @ScottHunter it determines a label for each student which can be "absent" or "present" for each day

Comment: `taking_attendence` has to know *which* instances of `Student` it will update.

Comment: You seem to want to build something like a student management system. So, to what extent do you want your code to work? Just do some basic stuff, or what do you plan on doing with the code? I guess I have some code similar to your needs; I will edit it according to your data.

Comment: The `Student` class needs a table of attendances for each day of the year. You pass a `Student` instance to `taking_attendance()`, then it can fill in the label for the current date in the given student.

Comment: @chepner I think that's one of the major problems my test code, thank you.

Comment: Why is `take_attendance()` in the `Teacher` class in the first place? What does it use from the Teacher instance?

Comment: It would make more sense if the teacher had a list of students. Then `Teacher.take_attendance()` could loop through that list.

Comment: @NeerajRoy yes. Honestly, it needs to be on a really basic a level, as basic as having some variables being returned in the terminal; or using os for some other parts.

Comment: A `class` class may make sense, it would hold the instances of students and teacher. that instance of teacher could have its `take_attendance()` method called where the instance of the `class` class in which it was present would be passed (which would contain the instantiated students). If that makes sense. In other words, I think you need more robustness in your objects in the form of a collection of students/teacher before you can take attendance. In short, "what are you taking the attendance of", the answer of which should be its own object.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know if you'll get notified of my comment because I don't know the way to this site yet, but I just wanted to say your guides truly helped me out and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Got it, you're welcome!